# HTML Table / readdir limit to <60 rows?

Tags: php, html, directory, limit, readdir

I am stumped at this... I am trying to list all the files in a directory and pull some info from them (specifically their csv files... and I need to print out the first row of each.)

Well, It will only actually print <60 rows in the browser, I have tried everything. Can anyone help/give me some advice? I'm not the best coder, but I just need this to work. :(

Code:

```
<style>
    .demo {
        border:3px solid #000000;
        border-collapse:collapse;
        padding:5px;
    }
    .demo th {
        border:3px solid #000000;
        padding:5px;
        background:#F0F0F0;
    }
    .demo td {
        border:3px solid #000000;
        padding:5px;
        background:#DCC4FD;
    }
</style>
<?php
exec('ulimit -S -n 9999999999');
echo "Current Simulations for the next 24 hours.";
$path = ".";
$dh = opendir($path);
$i=1;
echo '<html><body><table class="demo">\n\n';
while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false) {
    if($file != "." && $file != ".." && $file != "index.php" && $file != ".htaccess" && $file != "error_log" && $file != "cgi-bin") {
        if(fnmatch('*.csv', $file)) {
        $content = file($file);
        echo "<td> $file </td>";
        echo "\n<td>".str_replace(array(","), array("</td><td>", "</td>\n<td>"), $content[1])."</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
        }
        $i++;
    }
}
fclose($handle);
closedir($dh);
?>
```

See here: http://35.188.166.151/

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment so I will make it as answer.

Try put

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

at the beginning of your PHP code and see if any error occured. If any will be found, fix them.

Also, there are 2 points about format:

1) you missed opening `<tr>` tag
2) you can't use table for this purpose if there are different columns count in each file

Comment: I get:  Undefined offset: 1 in /zenbot4/scripts/auto_backtester/graphs.php on line 50... this is on new code but this happens on both codes.

Comment: This error is not critical. Try putting `ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);` at the beginning then to make sure that php script will be executed as long as possible

Comment: OK I switched to apache2, now I can see all of the file names, but, the files do contain information but it won't print out. I keep getting: Undefined offset 30......500

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at your php.ini.
I think max_execution_time could have a low value. Try to raise this setting a little bit higher.
Andrea